# Speed up printing of mesh in octave

Tags: octave, mesh

Exporting the mesh below took several minutes in Octave but only a few seconds in Matlab (On Ubuntu,Linux Mint and Windows). What can be done to speed up the process in Octave?

```
x = linspace(0,1,100);
y = linspace(0,1,5000);
[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
mesh(X,Y,ones(5000,100));
print -dpdf 'output.pdf' # Takes several minutes in octave
```

Things I have tried that didn't speed up the print process:

- Change graphics_toolkit to fltk, gnuplot and qt
- set terminal in gnuplot between a few different alternatives
- Running figure('visible','off') before plotting and printing
- Update Octave to 4.0.2
- Update Octave to 4.2.0

Comment: what OS are you using? can you try the most recently released version of Octave? (4.2.0)

Comment: Have updated the original post with the OS (Linux mint and Ubuntu). Will compile version 4.2.0 and  see if the code above runs faster.

Comment: Do you have a working setup to run the code above in reasonable time? Would like to try and mimic it.

Comment: Won't have access to one for a few.days and then it'll just be windows x64 on my laptop. This may warrant a post on the help list where a few people more familiar with the internals could chime in.

Comment: fwiw - i can confirm this is also slow in Octave 4.0.3 (for x64) on Windows 7

Comment: Will make a post to the help list to get some insight into the problem as suggested by Nick J

Answer (score 1):

The running time can be reduced significantly by creating the pdf directly instead of having an intermediate eps step. To do this set the graphic backend to gnuplot

```
graphics_toolkit('gnuplot')
```

and use the pdfcairo terminal by changing the print command to

```
print('-dpdfcairo','output.pdf')
```

This was suggested by Dmitri on the Octave help list. Thanks!

The above change cut the running time on my system from 60 to around 30 seconds. I still consider this to be fairly slow and exporting a similar plot directly in gnuplot can be done in around 12 seconds (still on my system). Something in the print command of Octave is creating a lot of overhead but what in particular is at the  current time unknown to me. I created a toy example to generate a similar plot and it's almost as fast as creating the plot natively in gnuplot (around 12 seconds).

```
%Generate data to plot
N = 100;
M = 5000;
[X, Y] = meshgrid(linspace(0,1,N),linspace(0,1,M));
md = [X(:) Y(:) ones(M*N,1)];
%Send to gnuplot
in = popen("gnuplot",'w');
fputs(in, "set term pdfcairo\n");
fputs(in, "set output 'out.pdf'\n");
mkfifo("/tmp/mypipe", 438)
fputs(in, "splot '/tmp/mypipe'\n");
save('-ascii','/tmp/mypipe','md');
system('rm /tmp/mypipe');
fputs(in, "quit\n");
fclose(in);
```